# Cutting text with javascript

Tags: javascript

How to cut text with javascript from input

I need to make

```
[19:00:14] Jacob Caderu > <url=fitting:17740:2048;1:26404;1:7783;8:2281;2:26442;1:19341;1:10190;4:19215;1:26448;1:17559;1:1999;2:31884;5:21740;13025:23051;2127:28668;200::>vindi dps</url>
```

to

```
<url=fitting:17740:2048;1:26404;1:7783;8:2281;2:26442;1:19341;1:10190;4:19215;1:26448;1:17559;1:1999;2:31884;5:21740;13025:23051;2127:28668;200::>
```

text is dynamic after and before

```
<url=fitting:17740:2048;1:26404;1:7783;8:2281;2:26442;1:19341;1:10190;4:19215;1:26448;1:17559;1:1999;2:31884;5:21740;13025:23051;2127:28668;200::>
```

Comment: You want to remove the `[19:00:14] Jacob Caderu > ` correct?

Comment: yes and some text at end vindi dps</url> but that text changes when other people paste

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want the part between `<url= .....>`

```
var str = '[19:00:14] Jacob Caderu > <url=fitting:17740:2048;1:26404;1:7783;8:2281;2:26442;1:19341;1:10190;4:19215;1:26448;1:17559;1:1999;2:31884;5:21740;13025:23051;2127:28668;200::>vindi dps</url>';

str = str.replace(/^.+?(<url=[^>]+>).+$/, '$1');

console.log(str);
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9vLw6/1/

Answer (score 0):

With a regexp:

```
var parts = /^.*(<url=[^>]*>).*$/.exec(input), output;
if (parts) {
    output = parts[1];
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, more simply:

```
string.split(' > ').slice(1).join(' > ')
```